# Problems with pushing data into an array, declaring a hash and conditional statements in Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, hash, conditional-statements

Can anyone help, I'm having problems with my Perl script. I want to push a 3-column data input file into an array, select ID numbers and names, declare a hash using both IDs as the key and the value as the values and then run an if-else conditional statement to select the key-value pairs that have a value greater than 2.

Here's an example of the `input.txt` data file where `column 1 is ID number, column 2 is ID name and column 3 value associated with columns 1 and 2`.

```
    ENSG00000251791 SCARNA6 2.5
    ENSG00000238862 SNORD19B 6.3
    ENSG00000238527 SN-112 -3
    ENSG00000222373 RNY.5P5 1.3
```

I can get the first part pushing the data into an array but I can't the rest of it to work. I've created two hashes that contain ID number:value and ID name:value pairs as I'd like both columns in the output file:

```
ENSG00000251791 SCARNA6 2.5
ENSG00000238862 SNORD19B 6.3
```

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input = 'input.txt';

my @input_vars;
open my $input_file_handle, '<', $input or die $!;

while (<$input_file_handle>) {
    chomp $_;
    push @input_vars, $_;
}
close $input_file_handle;
# regex to select ID name, ID number and value
my %id;
foreach (@input_vars) {
    my $regex = '/\w+\s[\w-]+\s\d+\.\d+/';
    while ($_ =~ m/$regex/g) {

            my $id1{$1} = $3;
            my $id2{$2} = $3;
    }
}
foreach (@input_vars) {
    print "$_ ";
    if ($id1{$_} >= 2) {
            print "$id1{$_}";
} else {
            print "N/A";
}
    if ($id2{$_} >= 2) {
    print "$id2{$_}";
} else {
    print "N/A";

 print "n";
}
```

I think I have over-complicated it by creating a regex to select ID numbers and names so if there's a simpler, more efficient way, that would be great.

Comment: There are no capture groups in your regex...

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to perl, could you explain please?

Comment: Where `$gene_exp1{$_}` and `$gene_exp2{$_}` come from?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I'll edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first foreach loop to:

```
foreach (@input_vars) {
    if (/(\w+)\s([\w-]+)\s(\d+\.\d+)$/) {
        $id1{$1} = $3;
        $id2{$2} = $3;
    }
}
```

Comment: <del>What is `my` doing there?</del>